# Compare 2 strings

Tags: bash, compare

I wrote this script for Nagios to check if a service is running.
However I need it to compare 2 strings. 
Full script below.

`elif [[ $PROCESS_RUNNING1 = "active" && $PROCESS_RUNNING2 = "(running)" || "(exited)" ]]; then`

If I run this through shellcheck it says it's wrong, because of the `||`. 
But how would I compare 2 strings, is this really the most efficient thing? Can this be shortened?

`elif [[ $PROCESS_RUNNING1 = "active" && $PROCESS_RUNNING2 = "(running)" || $PROCESS_RUNNING2 = "(exited)" ]]; then`

All other tips are very much welcome, I am still a beginner!

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
  case $1 in
    -s|--service)
        DAEMON=$2
        shift; shift
        ;;
    -*)
        echo "Unknown option: $1"
        echo "Usage: -s or --service <daemon name>"
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        break
        ;;
  esac
done

PROCESS_STATUS=$(systemctl status "$DAEMON" | awk 'FNR==3')
PROCESS_RUNNING1=$(systemctl status "$DAEMON" | awk 'FNR==3' | awk '{print $2}')
PROCESS_RUNNING2=$(systemctl status "$DAEMON" | awk 'FNR==3' | awk '{print $3}')

if [[ $(pgrep -f "$DAEMON" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "$DAEMON PID not found"
        exit 1
elif [[ $PROCESS_RUNNING1 != "active" ]]; then
        echo "$PROCESS_STATUS"
        echo "is not active"
        exit 2
elif [[ $PROCESS_RUNNING2 != "(running)" || "(exited)" ]]; then
        echo "$PROCESS_STATUS"
        echo "is not running or exited"
        exit 2
elif [[ $PROCESS_RUNNING1 = "active" && $PROCESS_RUNNING2 = "(running)" || "(exited)" ]]; then
        echo "$PROCESS_STATUS"
        exit 0
else    echo "$DAEMON status unknown, please check"
        exit 3
fi
```

Comment: You can utilize extended globbing: `[[ $foo = active && $bar = @(running|exited) ]]`. You can enable it with `shopt -s extglob`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bash

```
$PROCESS_RUNNING2 = "(running)" || "(exited)"
```

is about the same as

```
"(exited)" || $PROCESS_RUNNING2 = "(running)"
```

which evaluates to *true* no matter what.

When you write just a string in `[[ ... ]]` without using any operators like `=`, then that string is interpreted as *true* for non-empty strings and *false* for the empty string.

You probably meant

```
[[ "$PROCESS_RUNNING1" = "active" && "$PROCESS_RUNNING2" = "(running)"
   || "$PROCESS_RUNNING2" = "(exited)" ]]
```

or even more likely, the parenthesized version

```
[[ "$PROCESS_RUNNING1" = "active" &&
   ("$PROCESS_RUNNING2" = "(running)" || "$PROCESS_RUNNING2" = "(exited)") ]]
```

which ensures, that the first condition always has to hold.

### Further Improvements

#### Hint 1

```
PROCESS_STATUS=$(systemctl status "$DAEMON" | awk 'FNR==3')
PROCESS_RUNNING1=$(systemctl status "$DAEMON" | awk 'FNR==3' | awk '{print $2}')
PROCESS_RUNNING2=$(systemctl status "$DAEMON" | awk 'FNR==3' | awk '{print $3}')
```

can be written more efficiently as

```
PROCESS_STATUS=$(systemctl status "$DAEMON" | awk 'FNR==3')
PROCESS_RUNNING1=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$PROCESS_STATUS")
PROCESS_RUNNING2=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< "$PROCESS_STATUS")
```

#### Hint 2

Instead of

```
if [[ $(pgrep -f "$DAEMON" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
```

write

```
if ! pgrep -f "$DAEMON"; then
```

#### Hint 3

The check

```
[[ $PROCESS_RUNNING2 != "(running)" || "(exited)" ]]
```

is always *true*. Even if you meant

```
[[ $PROCESS_RUNNING2 != "(running)" || $PROCESS_RUNNING2 != "(exited)" ]]
```

In order to evaluate to *false*, `$PROCESS_RUNNING2` had to have value `"(running)"` and `("exited")` at the same time.

#### Hint 4

Environment and built-in variables are written in *ALLCAPS*. Write your own variables in *camelCase* to avoid name collisions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, it helped more then you think, and helps me become more efficient!! My last question, `[[ "$PROCESS_RUNNING1" = "active" &&
   ("$PROCESS_RUNNING2" = "(running)" || "$PROCESS_RUNNING2" = "(exited)") ]]`, is there any more efficient way for this, or does it 'have to be' that long?

Comment: @Florius You could replace `$var = 1 || $var = 2` with `$var =~ "1"|"2"`. Shorter variable names also help.

Comment: Any suggestions for shorter variable names? How do you come up with them? I'm terrible at something that makes sense.
Also, I used your suggestions, but unfortunately it doesn't have the desired effect: https://pastebin.com/MjqCebGg
It still exit's on my second `if` statement, even while it shouldn't?

Comment: @Florius check hint 3, you still have `||` where it should be `&&`.

Comment: @PesaThe Unfortunately that doesn't work: `elif [[ "$proc_running2" != "(running)" && "$proc_running2" != "(exited)" ]]; then`, it gives the same result.

Comment: @Florius You have `print $2` twice.

Comment: @PesaThe Yeap, I just figured that out, copy/paste error, my bad! So it worked as intended, I was just an idiot :)